# gcc undefined reference error on Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-construction

I have a strange problem and i have gone through all similar questions but can't find an answer.

I am trying to compile some code which keeps throwing up undefined reference error even though the library is specified using -l and is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH too. I can't figure out the reason. Here is an example

> gcc -L/home/sam/gmdb/lib -L/home/sam/db/add-ons/lib
>   -L/home/sam/convert/lib -L/home/sam/rtana/lib -L/home/sam/rtana/add-ons/lib   -o /home/sam/gmdb/bin/server /home/sam/db/obj/tools/server/server.o
>   /home/sam/db/obj/tools/common/tool_data_parse.o
>   /home/sam/db/obj/tools/common/tool_param.o
>   /home/sam/gmdb/obj/tools/common/tool_public.o -lgmcommon
>   -L/home/sam/db/add-ons/vpp/lib/suse -lipsi_crypto -lipsi_osal -lipsi_pse -lipsi_ssl -lgmmd5 -lgmkernel -lgmpl -lgmrep -lgmsqlserver -lgmsqlclient -lconvert -lrtana -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lre2 -lboost_timer -lnuma -lpthread -lm -lrt

The list of undefined errors is long but the first one is

> /home/usama/convert/lib/libconvert.so: undefined reference to
>   `numa_num_configured_cpus'

So as you can see it's complaining about a method in libnuma. libnuma is provided a -lnuma as you can see, and is present in /usr/lib

The error mentions libconvert which is just a shared library that has a call to numa_num_configured_cpus but is not linked with libnuma, and it shouldn't matter since libconvert is just an so file. I am providing the -lnuma while generating the executable as you can see above. Here is the nm out on libconvert

```
nm -C -u convert/lib/libconvert.so | grep numa*
                 U google::protobuf::internal::NameOfEnum(google::protobuf::EnumDescriptor const*, int)
                 U numa_num_configured_cpus
                 U numa_num_configured_nodes
```

I did try to compile with --unresolved-symbols, which results in successful compilation but the binary doesn't run again complaining about undefined symbols.

My GCC version is

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And Ubuntu is 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10

Does anyone have a clue if i am hitting a bug or what is going on?

Comment: Can you find the symbol `numa_num_configured_cpus` in `libnuma`? Oddly enough the order of libraries is already correct (if this is the exact command you use).

Comment: As pmr points out, the output of running nm on /usr/lib/libnuma*.so would be very helpful. I see there's some C++ going on in libconvert - could it be a mismatch in whether the symbols should be C++-mangled or not?

Comment: Is the libnuma in the /usr/lib path a .a or a .so?  You will need the .a to compile.  If you don't have it you will need to get the package.  Also, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used at run-time to search for .so files and fix them up with executable. It should have no effect on the compile.

Comment: Could you post the output of `nm -u libconvert.so libnuma.so` (no `-C` unmangling)?

Comment: As @MagnusReftel points out, there is C++ stuff in libconvert -- have you tried linking with g++ instead of gcc?

Answer (score 7):

Guys thank you for your comments. The problem as i found that is because the default behavior of gcc is changed in Ubuntu (at-least the version i am using) The hint is on this wiki page of debian https://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking

According to this the gcc is changed to add --as-needed to the linker. The down side of this behavior is that and i quote the wiki " Binaries, which are using symbols from an indirectly linked shared library will fail to link "

This was exactly the problem with me, as libconvert was using libnuma, but not linked to it, and the binary i was building tried to link everything including both libconvert and libnuma to it. The default gcc would work because it uses no-as-needed behavior which is changed in Debian and made it to Ubuntu as well.

So in short the linking works if i add `-Wl,--no-as-needed`.

> gcc -Wl,--no-as-needed -L/home/sam/gmdb/lib -L/home/sam/db/add-ons/lib
>   -L/home/sam/convert/lib -L/home/sam/rtana/lib -L/home/sam/rtana/add-ons/lib -o /home/sam/gmdb/bin/server /home/sam/db/obj/tools/server/server.o
>   /home/sam/db/obj/tools/common/tool_data_parse.o
>   /home/sam/db/obj/tools/common/tool_param.o
>   /home/sam/gmdb/obj/tools/common/tool_public.o -lgmcommon
>   -L/home/sam/db/add-ons/vpp/lib/suse -lipsi_crypto -lipsi_osal -lipsi_pse -lipsi_ssl -lgmmd5 -lgmkernel -lgmpl -lgmrep -lgmsqlserver -lgmsqlclient -lconvert -lrtana -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lre2 -lboost_timer -lnuma -lpthread -lm -lrt

Comment: I was experiencing the same damned problem.  Three days of investigation turned up nothing.  This was the answer.  Many thanks!